# I need to pass a JSON file to MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I tried this, but it does not work:
The readFile works well, and it finishes before the connection to the DB had started.
My problem is when trying to use the parsed JSON obj (listingData) into MongoDB using Mongoose.

```
 let listingData;
 fs.readFile('listings.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
   try {
     listingData = JSON.parse(data);
   } catch (err) {
     console.log('Error reading JSON file');
     throw err;
   }
   //console.log(listingData); // PRINTS DATA CORRECTLY!
 });

 async function loadListings() {
   try {
     await Listing.insertMany(listingData); // imported.insertMany(JSON Parsed)
     console.log("Listings inserted in the DB");
     //process.exit();
   } catch (error) {
     console.log("Error importing listings to DB");
     process.exit();
   }
 }
```

**SOLVED, thanks**

Answer (score 1):

Both the `readFile` and `loadListings` is async so `loadListing` is not going to wait for `readFile` to finish and pass the data as by that time `listingData` is`undefined`.

You can solve this issue by using promise library of `fs`. Available after `node 10.x` version

```
  const fs= require(fs).promises

async function loadListings() {
   try {
     let listingData= await fs.readFile('listings.json','utf8')// Get data here, await will wait for execution to finish
     await Listing.insertMany(listingData);
     console.log("Listings inserted in the DB");
     //process.exit();
   } catch (error) {
     console.error(error) // Catch Error here
     console.log("Error importing listings to DB");
     process.exit();
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, Solved it differently, but will check Promises to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you checked fs.readfile, you'd notice that it's an async function.

So loadlistings will NOT wait for readfile to finish.

There are two ways to fix this, a bad way, and a good way.

The *bad* way is for you to remove async from loadlistings, and turn readfile into readfilesync. This is **BAD** because it is **NOT the node.js** way... async as much as possible.

Instead, you should learn how to leverage async properly by incorporating `readfile` INTO loadlistings as a promise. Which is the solution @Shivam Sood gave you.

Comment: I tried option 1 (bad one), and it ran. Not correctly tho.
I solved it the easy way, just moved the insertions to the end of readFile.
 
Thank you for explaining, I'm still learning.